# How to send object in MKAnnotation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkannotation

I want to send object when user taps on pin. I know only how to send title but this is not enough because some titles are same.

This is my code:

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (context == nil) 
    { 
        context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }


    /* ********************************************** */
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Offers" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

//[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subOffer == %@", self.subItem];
[request setPredicate:predicate];


NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"offerOrder" ascending:YES];

NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

[request setSortDescriptors:newArray];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

//NSLog(@"%@", results);


/* **************************************************** */

    mapView.delegate=self;

    NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
    theCoordinate1.latitude = 43.82078;
    theCoordinate1.longitude = 15.307265;



    for (Offers *offer in results){

        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;

        MyAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

        theCoordinate1.latitude = [offer.lat doubleValue];
        theCoordinate1.longitude = [offer.lon doubleValue];

        myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
        myAnnotation1.title = offer.offerName;
        myAnnotation1.subtitle = offer.offerLocation;


        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
        [annotations addObject:myAnnotation1];



    }//end for



    //NSLog(@"%d",[annotations count]);


    //[self gotoLocation];//to catch perticular area on screen
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // Walk the list of overlays and annotations and create a MKMapRect that
    // bounds all of them and store it into flyTo.
    MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {

        //NSLog(@"fly to on");

        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
            flyTo = pointRect;
        } else {
            flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
            //NSLog(@"else-%@",annotationPoint.x);
            //NSLog(@"else");
        }
    }





    // Position the map so that all overlays and annotations are visible on screen.
    mapView.visibleMapRect = flyTo;




    UIBarButtonItem* temp=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    temp.title=@"Back";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=temp;
    //[temp release];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
    pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;


    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showDetails:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;


    return pinView;
}

-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{

    //NSLog(@"Annotation Click");


    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    detail.title = ((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];



}
...
```

Comment: At least I don't understand fully what you mean. Could you be a bit more specific and point out *exactly* where you want to do what? Thanks.

Comment: I want to send offer object in IBAction "showDetails" when user taps on pin.

Comment: Okay, but where do you get this Offer object from? Did you store it somehow? Is there only one offer object you want to pass?

Comment: in "viewDidLoad" I'm storing offers. You'll see following code: ...for (Offers *offer in results){...

Comment: First: I have to assume results is an ivar. In this case you aren't technically storing anything. You are just enumerating on these offer objects. Do you want to pass all these objects? Or just a specific one? On what base are you able to decide on the question *which* object to pass?

Comment: added code over which I'm getting all objects. I want to pass only one object, object on which marker/pin user click/tap.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11974/discussion-between-pbx-and-croios)